# Windows Store Apps - Let user to remove trial mode via code

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

I have developed application which supports trial mode. But now I need let some users to get full via activation code. Scenario is user downloads trial application and he can enter activation code for the app and then user can use full features of the app.

Can anyone please suggest me a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to think about how you will authenticate the code - I'm guessing that you don't want them to authenticate the code via the store so you will have to provide some backend service to do this.

The service will obviously require the activation code to be sent to it (you should store this in the remotesettings), and you might perhaps want a device unique ID sent to - you can use the [unique id](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken) for this.

Your service should then validate how many times it has seen the code, and if it's happy it should [hash](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256.aspx) the code, the device ID, and a secret shared with your application - this will need to be embedded inside your app code.

For additional privacy for the user I would advice hashing the device unique ID with the shared secret before sending it to the server.

You need to store the returned activation code inside your app - and there isn't a lot of choice - I would personally store this code in the [LocalSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings) area.

Now on startup you need to verify that the stored activation code is valid. If you have an internet connection then you can do this by asking the service if the code is valid, but you must make an arrangement for offline checking. This is simple enough as the activation code, plus the hashed device ID hashed against the shared secret should equal the stored activation code - depending on your type of application you might want to only allow 5 activations this way before requiring internet access (pick a high number as this could really annoy users)

Finally you need to consider users that have multiple devices - according to the store you can have 5 installs of the same application, for the same users, across different devices. To accommodate this we have stored the activation code in remotesettings, so on startup check if the code exists, and if it does automatically send the code and the device id to your service for activation.

The only other thing you need to consider is how on earth do you secure the shared secret in your application? Unfortunately there aren't many options for this. It really depends on how secure your app need to be. If you are totally paranoid then obfuscate your code, but this just buys time. If you need more than that then I suggest you send the device code, hashed with a cryptographically random nonce to your service, this will return back what you sent, but hashed with the secret. Unfortunately this will make offline validation of the activation token impossible, so you will have to build in a grace period where internet connection is not required.

Or you could use in app purchases.

Comment: Thanks a lot for explanation, but thing is, I didn't found any way to convert trial version to full version without doing any payment to store. What I tried was In-App Purchases, but when I try to purchase app, it will ask user to log-in to store and deduct payment from his account. But what I wanted to do is, user to download trial version and activate application using given code (without paying in store).

Comment: Thats fine, just make the app free, and use your own code to decide if it's a trial or not.

Comment: Is there any way I can do this with keeping store purchases and trial mode. Reason I need this is, I want give some few users to free licences. For example reviewers. So, I just need this functionality to licences to selected number of users. All other users will have to user either trial or full from store. And thanks a lot for quick reply. :)

Comment: In your app, when you check the logic to see if the app is purchase, or still running in trial mode, just include the above check.